# Merge two datatables in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two datatables ..

```
DataTable dtTemp= new DataTable();
            dtTemp.Columns.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new DataColumn("segment_id", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("seg_description")
            });


DataTable dtTemp2 = new DataTable();
dtTemp2.Columns.Add("set_id",typeof(int));
```

Now lets have some rows into first table..

```
segment_id|seg_description
------    |---------------
   1      | desc..
   2      | desc2..
   3      | desc3..
```

Now lets have some data into second table..

```
 set_id
--------
   1
--------
   2
```

Now, I want marge this two tables to get below output

```
set_id  | segment_id |seg_description
--------| ---------- | --------------
    1   |    1       |  desc..
    1   |    2       | desc2..
    1   |    3       | desc3..
    2   |    1       |   desc..
    2   |    2       | desc2..
    2   |    3       | desc3..
```

How can I do this?using Merge() can I achieve this?

Comment: output = table 1 x table 2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to "cross-join" the tables by building a cartesian product of all rows? Of course there is no builtin way, you can use this method:

```
public static DataTable CrossJoinTables(DataTable t1, DataTable t2)
{
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("t1 or t2", "Both tables must not be null");

    DataTable t3 = t1.Clone();  // first add columns from table1
    foreach (DataColumn col in t2.Columns)
    {
        string newColumnName = col.ColumnName;
        int colNum = 1;
        while (t3.Columns.Contains(newColumnName))
        {
            newColumnName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", col.ColumnName, ++colNum);
        }
        t3.Columns.Add(newColumnName, col.DataType);
    }

    IEnumerable<object[]> crossJoin = 
        from r1 in t1.AsEnumerable()
        from r2 in t2.AsEnumerable()
        select r1.ItemArray.Concat(r2.ItemArray).ToArray();

    foreach(object[] allFields in crossJoin)
    {
        t3.Rows.Add(allFields);
    }

    return t3;
}
```

Usage:

```
DataTable tblresult = CrossJoinTables(dtTemp2, dtTemp); // swapped order because you want columns from dtTemp2 first
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use the [CROSS JOIN](https://www.essentialsql.com/cross-join-introduction/) operation.

```
Select * Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2
```

It literally gives you the product of the two tables : Every row in A joined to every row in B.  if A has 100 rows and B has 100 rows, the Cross Join has 10,000 rows.

Comment: Thats not SQL but `DataTable` which is a .NET collection

Comment: I gues I can do cross join using Linq ?@TimSchmelter any other way ?

Comment: @Nody then you might want to accept answer to close this

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var dt1 = dtTemp1.AsEnumerable();
var dt2 = dtTemp2.AsEnumerable();

var q = from x in dt1
        from y in dt2
        select new { set_id = (int)y["set_id"], segment_id = (int)x["segment_id"], seg_description = (string)x["seg_description"] };
```

Comment: DataTable do not implement IEnumerable, In fact they existed before IEnumerable so no Querry directly on it.

Comment: dtTemp2.rows is queryable and has everything you need.